# Speed up the jQuery-ajax being used Custom filters and show results without delay

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, filter

I'm using a filter based on jQuery ajax. Filter is working quite perfectly but the issue is because it's using the ajax call due to yearly based search so it's a bit slow , I mean when user selects year he/she have to wait for next option to enable and as options are based on year so they take some time to load in filter.

I need to sort this out quickly can you please help me out here ?

Below is the php and jQuery code for that please see and help me out . Thanks

Here is code for form which is working as filters:

---

```
<form id="search-product" method="GET" action="<? bloginfo('url') ?>/product/">

                  <div class="search-field">

                    <select id="select-yr" name="yr" required="">

                        <option value="">Year</option>

                            <?php foreach(get_data_yrs() as $yr) { ?>
                                <option<?= (isset($_GET['yr']) && $_GET['yr'] == $yr ? " selected" : "") ?>><?= $yr ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>

                    </select>

                  </div>

                  <div class="search-field">

                    <select id="select-make" name="make" required="" data-selected="<?= (isset($_GET['make']) ? $_GET['make'] : "") ?>">Select make</select>

                  </div>

                  <div class="search-field">

                    <select id="select-model" name="model" required data-selected="<?= (isset($_GET['model']) ? $_GET['model'] : "") ?>">Select model</select>

                  </div>

                  <div class="search-field">

                    <select id="select-qualifier" name="qualifier" data-selected="<?= (isset($_GET['qualifier']) ? $_GET['qualifier'] : "") ?>">Select qualifier</select>

                  </div>  


                  <div class="search-sub">

                    <input type="submit" name="srh" value="Search">

                   <input type="reset" value="Reset">

                  </div>

              </form>
```

And here is the jQuery :

```
  $("#select-yr").on("change", onYearChange);
    $("#select-make").on("change", onMakeChange);
    $("#select-model").on("change", onModelChange);

    $("#select-yr").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != "") {
            $(this).trigger("change");
        }
    });

    function onYearChange() {
        var $selectors = $("#select-make, #select-model, #select-qualifier");
        var $selector = $("#select-make");

        var $yr = $("#select-yr").val();
        var $selected = $selector.data("selected");

        $selectors.empty();
        $selector.append('<option>Please wait</option>');
      //  $selector.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'get_data_makes',
                yr: $yr
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $selectors.empty();
                $selector.append('<option value="">Select Make</option>');

                if(data.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        $selector.append('<option'+(data[i] == $selected ? " selected" : "")+'>'+data[i]+'</option>');
                    }
                }

                if($selected) {
                    $selector.trigger('change');
                }

                $selector.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }

    function onMakeChange() {
        var $selectors = $("#select-model, #select-qualifier");
        var $selector = $("#select-model");

        var $make = $("#select-make").val();
        var $yr = $("#select-yr").val();
        var $selected = $selector.data("selected");

        $selectors.empty();
        $selector.append('<option>Please wait</option>');
        $selector.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'get_data_models',
                make: $make,
                yr: $yr
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $selectors.empty();
                $selector.append('<option value="">Select Model</option>');

                if(data.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        $selector.append('<option'+(data[i] == $selected ? " selected" : "")+'>'+data[i]+'</option>');
                    }
                }

                if($selected) {
                    $selector.trigger('change');
                }

                $selector.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }

    function onModelChange() {
        var $selectors = $("#select-qualifier");
        var $selector = $("#select-qualifier");

        var $make = $("#select-make").val();
        var $yr = $("#select-yr").val();
        var $model = $("#select-model").val();
        var $selected = $selector.data("selected");

        $selectors.empty();
        $selector.append('<option>Please wait</option>');
        $selector.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'get_data_qualifiers',
                make: $make,
                yr: $yr,
                model: $model
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $selectors.empty();
                $selector.append('<option value="">Select Qualifier</option>');

                if(data.length > 0) {
                    for(var i in data) {
                        $selector.append('<option'+(data[i] == $selected ? " selected" : "")+'>'+data[i]+'</option>');
                    }
                }

                if($selected) {
                    $selector.trigger('change');
                }

                $selector.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can try async and await

Comment: Will it work  ? and I think it's currently functioning asynchronously

Comment: BTW you talked about await , can you please let me know how does it work ? And how can I use it in my code ?